# Qt segfault trying to show 2 dialogs in test application

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, dialog

I'm just learning Qt. I reproduced my problem in a simple test application. I created a new project. Added 2 dialogs Dialog1 and Dialog2. I added 2 menu entries to call dialog1 and dialog2.

The main window's header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "dialog1.h"
#include "dialog2.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_actiondialog1_triggered();

    void on_actiondialog2_triggered();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Dialog1 *mDialog1;
    Dialog2 *mDialog2;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

The main window's cpp looks like this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
      , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_actiondialog1_triggered()
{
     if (!mDialog1) {
        mDialog1 = new Dialog1(this);
        mDialog1->setModal(false);
     }
     mDialog1->show();
     mDialog1->activateWindow();
 }

 void MainWindow::on_actiondialog2_triggered()
 {

    if (!mDialog2) {
        mDialog2 = new Dialog2(this);
        mDialog2->setModal(false);
    }
    mDialog2->show();
    mDialog2->activateWindow();
 }
```

So it is basically as empty as it gets... If I only show one dialog by commenting out the relevant sections it works but as soon as I want to use 2 or more is segfaults. The given dialogs constructor isn't even being called anymore.

I am using:

```
Qt Creator 4.12.3
Based on Qt 5.14.2 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit)
Built on Jun 16 2020 04:15:35
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Did you use the Debugger to see where it segfaults? I would initialise those **Dialog** pointers with nullptr and then I would check if (mDialog1 != nullptr).

Comment: Yes I did. I also changed the code as per your suggestions but it is still the same. The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the opreating system.
Signal name: SIGSEGV
Signal meaning: Segmentation fault

in the file qwidget.cpp line 7914
Qt::WindowState defaultState = QGuiApplicationPrivate::platformIntegration()->defaultWindowState(data->window_flags); It's in the method void QWidget::show()

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, there is an error in the suggestions. the problem is that you should check if mDialog1 == nullptr. Without this, of course it crashes because you call a non initialized ponter. So you should initialize mDialog1 and mDialog2 to nullptr and then change the code to if (mDialog1 == nullptr). In this way, if the pointer is null, you initialize it and create the corresponding class.

Comment: You are correct. It functions now. Combined with the answer beneath I understand what I did wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is not about Qt. It is about your implementation:In  your constructor, I don't see code, which initializes mDialog1 and mDialog2.
So, when go to the slot what is the value of mDialog1 ? It is undefined, especially in Release build.
Here is one of the approaches:
In your constructor, just create the objects:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
  , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mDialog1 = new Dialog1(this);
    mDialog2 = new Dialog2(this);
}
```

Then in slot (you don't need to check the pointer):

```
void MainWindow::on_actiondialog1_triggered()
{
     mDialog1->setModal(false); //Not required, because of show()
     mDialog1->show();
     mDialog1->activateWindow();
 }
```

Another approach, which creates objects on demand:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
  , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
//Initalize these members
m_dialog1 = nullptr;
m_dialog2 = nullptr;

}
```

And then:

```
 void MainWindow::on_actiondialog2_triggered()
 {

if (!mDialog2) 
{
    mDialog2 = new Dialog2(this);
    mDialog2->setModal(false);
}
mDialog2->show();
mDialog2->activateWindow();
```

}